# Debugging Array and for-loop + if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, error-handling

I have built a method which compares objects attributes with user input int. The method then adds all the objects to an array(the assignment demands it to be an Array and not ArrayList). After its added I have a foor-loop which prints out a list of Results for an athlete(in user input), it prints out all results from one category and then another and so forth..

I keep getting a NullPointerException error on the last line which is a System.out.println. I have searched for an answer for hours, and read the NullPointerException posts here but cannot find the issue or solve it.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < category.size(); x++) {
        Category c = categories.get(x);
        System.out.println("Result in " + c.categoryName() + " for " + matchedAthlete.surName() + " "
                + matchedAthlete.lastName() + ": ");
        for (int i = 0; i < individarrayresult.length; i++) {
            Result res = individarrayresult[i];
            if (res.nameOfCategory().equals(c.categoryName())) {
                System.out.println(res.categoryResult());
            }
        }
    }
```

So the last line of code ( System.out.println ) gets the NullPointerException, I am desperete for help. Below is the Array filled with results from only 1 Athlete.

```
     Result[] individarrayresult = new Result[resultlist.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.size(); i++) {
        Result res = resultlist.get(i);
        if (res.athleteStartNumber() == DSN) {
            individarrayresult[i] = res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace. (But I think that @DavideLorenzoMARINO has the right answer).

Comment: @AndyTurner: I was going to post some geek-topical comment like "I find your lack of faith disturbing" but your comment predated my answer by a couple of minutes, so... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mistaken, I think you're getting the NPE one line earlier, on this line:

```
if (res.nameOfCategory().equals(c.categoryName())) {
```

And the reason you're getting it is there are `null`s in your array, because of how you fill it:

```
Result[] individarrayresult = new Result[resultlist.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.size(); i++) {
    Result res = resultlist.get(i);
    if (res.athleteStartNumber() == DSN) {
        individarrayresult[i] = res;
    }
}
```

If `res.athleteStartNumber() == DSN` is false, you never assign anything to `individarrayresult[i]`, so that array entry keeps its `null` default.

How to fix it:

Build up a list of matching results:

```
List<> individResults = new Arraylist<Result>(resultlist.size());

for (int i = 0; i < resultlist.size(); i++) {
    Result res = resultlist.get(i);
    if (res.athleteStartNumber() == DSN) {
        individResults.add(res);
    }
}
```

...and then either use that list directly, or convert it to an array:

```
Result[] individarrayresult = individResults.toArray(new Result[individResults.size()]);
```

...and use the resulting array.

(You can also do the same with the nifty new streams stuff in the latest version of Java, but I'm not au fait with them...)

---

It's possible, of course, that you're getting the NPE on the line you said you are and that there are **two** problems, and it just happens you've been processing all DSN entries so far. If so, and you fix the other problem, the first time you have a non-DSN entry, you'll run into this problem unless it fix it as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `NullPointerException` on that row:

```
System.out.println(res.categoryResult());
```

The problem is in the method `categoryResult` because **res is not null**, otherwyse the previous test

```
if (res.nameOfCategory().equals(c.categoryName())) {
```

must throw the NullPointerException prior of the System.out.

So check the code of `categoryResult()` or post it.

---

Perhaps, as T.J. said, that the problem is not on that row but on the previous row and the NullPointerException is related to the value of res. Post the complete StackTrace and row lines of your code to be sure of that answer.

Comment: *"If you have a NullPointerException on that row:"* You'd be right if they were, of course, but they must be misreporting that, given the code they've quoted.

Comment: I assumed that at least the question was correct (not the code).